# Cascading dropdown with angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, cascadingdropdown

I am trying to create cascading dropdowns with angular js and nested json.

This is my json:

```
'ListItems':[ {
               'CountryName':'India',
                  'states': [{
                     'stateName':'Maharashtra',
                         'cities': 
                           [{'cityName':'Pune'}, 
                            {'cityName':'Mumbai'}, 
                            {'cityName':'Nagpur'},
                            {'cityName': 'Akola'}
                           ]},
                       {
                     'stateName':'Madhya Pradesh',
                         'cities': 
                           [{'cityName':'Indore'}, 
                            {'cityName':'Bhopal'}, 
                            {'cityName':'Jabalpur'}
                           ]} 
                      ]},
                 {
               'CountryName':'USA',
                  'states': [{
                     'stateName':'Alabama',
                         'cities': 
                           [{'cityName':'Montgomery'}, 
                            {'cityName':'Birmingham'}
                           ]},
                       {
                     'stateName':'California',
                         'cities': 
                           [{'cityName':'Los-Angeles'}, 
                            {'cityName':'San-Francisco'}
                           ]} 
                      ]}
```

There are two countries. Each country includes states and each state includes cities.

Comment: If this turns out to not be a duplicate, it should still be closed because your question doesn't show any effort to accomplish this yourself.

Comment: Not even clear what intended results are, I interpret cascading dropdown as `<select>` but others think it's a `<ul>` structure. Provide expected results and your attempts to achieve those results

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat to parse the elements

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in ListItems">
        {{item}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="state in item" >{{state.stateName}}</li>
            ... etc
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
```